# Instantiate a new obj using Go reflect and type assert to an interface

Tags: go, go-reflect

I can't explain why the following is working.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

type MyInterface interface {
    someFunc()
}

type Dock struct {
}

func (d *Dock) someFunc() {
}

type Group struct {
    Docks []Dock `better:"sometag"`
}

func foo(model interface{}) {
    v1 := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(model))
    for i := 0; i < v1.NumField(); i++ {
        tag := v1.Type().Field(i).Tag.Get("better")
        if strings.HasPrefix(tag, "sometag") {
            inter := v1.Field(i).Interface()
            typ := reflect.TypeOf(inter).Elem()
            fmt.Println("Type:", typ.String())

            // Want to instantiate type like &Dock{} then assign it to some interface,
            // but using reflect
            n := reflect.New(typ)
            _, ok := n.Interface().(MyInterface)            
            fmt.Println("Why is it OK?", ok)

        }
    }
}

func main() {
    g := &Group{}
    foo(g)

    /*var v1, v2 interface{}
    d1 := &Dock{}
    v1 = d1
    _, ok1 := v1.(MyInterface)

    d2 := Dock{}
    v2 = d2
    _, ok2 := v2.(MyInterface)
    fmt.Println(ok1, ok2)*/
}
```

It prints

```
Type: main.Dock
OK? true
```

If it's a Dock type, then it's not a pointer to Dock. Why does it conforms to `MyInterface`?

https://play.golang.org/p/Z9mR8amYOM7

Where as the d2 example in the comment does not.

Comment: go doc reflect.New: "New returns a Value representing a **pointer** to a new zero value for the specified type. That is, the returned Value's Type is PtrTo(typ)." Always, literally _always_ read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `go` [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#New) for `reflect.New`

> New returns a Value representing a pointer to a new zero value for the
>   specified type. That is, the returned Value's Type is PtrTo(typ).

```
n := reflect.New(typ)
fmt.Println("Type:", n.String())
```

It will print `Type: <*main.Dock Value>` means `n` is a pointer of `Dock`.You miss the part using `reflect.New` return the pointer.